# Construct a unique multi-part id with cummulative numbering by group

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
data_source <-c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1")
lake <-c("blue lake", "blue lake", "blue lake", "mirror lake", "mirror lake", 
         "mirror lake")
sample <-c("upper", "mid", "bottom", "upper", "mid", "bottom")
df <-data.frame(cbind(data_source, lake, sample))
df
```

I have constructed the following id columns:

```
df$source_id <-"s1"
df$lake_id <-paste(df$source_id, as.numeric(df$lake), sep = "_")
df$sample_id <-paste(df$lake_id, as.numeric(as.factor(df$lake_id)), sep = "_")
```

However, I want the `sample_id` column to look like this:

`df$desired_id <-c("s1_l1_1", "s1_l1_2", "s1_l1_3", "s1_l2_1", "s1_l2_2", "s1_l2_3")`

I can't figure out how to calculate a cumulative sample number by lake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029235/cumulative-count-in-r

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never ask for the "l" before the lake number in the `lake_id` column and that gets passed to the `sample_id` column.  Using code similar to what you're using, I'd do the following:

```
df$lake_id <- with(df, paste0(source_id, "_l", as.numeric(df$lake)))
# "s1_l1" "s1_l1" "s1_l1" "s1_l2" "s1_l2" "s1_l2"
```

This is different that now the lake_id contains an "l" before the lake number.

Now, your code will have the desired `sample_id` by running the rest of your code.

My preferred coding style when putting together multiple items like this is to use sprintf like this:

```
df$sample_id <- with(df, sprintf("%s_l%d_%d", source_id, as.numeric(lake), as.numeric(lake)))
```

With that coding style, it is a bit easier to see what is used and how it is connected-- with the added complexity of using sprintf formatting strings.