# How to Add counter at the end of unique rows given three different unique columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm adding the counter to the end of the unique rows but unable to do.I have 4 columns namely "ID", "Name","Amount".The problem I'm facing is that i want to add counter at the end of unique row "Id" column but make sure that i am also considering other unique rows as well.

This is the data frame i am using.

```
   Amount    ID Name
0     110  c121  abc
1     120  c121  abc
2     120  c123  sdd
3     140  c124  eet

df = {'ID':['c121', 'c121', 'c123', 'c124'], 'Name':['abc', 'abc','sdd','eet'],'Amount':[110,120,120,140]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

current df

```
 Amount    ID Name
0     110  c121  abc
1     120  c121  abc
2     120  c123  sdd
3     140  c124  eet
```

Expected result:

```
 Amount    ID    Name
0     110  c121_1  abc
1     120  c121_2  abc
2     120  c123    sdd
3     140  c124    eet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only duplicated values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), filter them with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) for starting by `1`, convert values to strings and use [`Series.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.radd.html) for add `_` with right side. Then assign to filtered `ID` column with `+=`:

```
#for test duplicates in ID column
m = df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)
#for test duplicates in Name and ID columns
#m = df.duplicated(['Name', 'ID'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'ID'] += df[m].groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('_')
```

Alternative:

```
df.loc[m, 'ID'] = df.loc[m, 'ID'] + '_' + df[m].groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

print (df)
       ID Name  Amount
0  c121_1  abc     110
1  c121_2  abc     120
2    c123  sdd     120
3    c124  eet     140
```

Comment: Are you also considering other unique columns while adding counter?

Comment: @Maddy6 - Yes, then need `m = df.duplicated(['Name', 'ID'], keep=False)`

Comment: can you tell me how to do same thing in R using dplyr

Comment: @Maddy6 - Sorry, but I no idea, becasue `R` is hard for me, but found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029235/cumulative-count-in-r)

Comment: Can you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008017/generic-script-for-bar-and-line-chart